# cross-hatching using PostScript

Tags: postscript

I am looking for a way to cross-hatch various basic shapes. Is there a fill style I can't find or should I use clipping?

Answer (score 4):

Check chapter 4.9:Patterns of the PostScript Language Reference Manual v.3, available at the the Adobe website